Can I regrout a tile wall damaged by foundation work?
I had some foundation work done, which cracked bathroom shower tile on the wall. Was going to clean out broken grout, and regrout but noticed what looks to be drywall separated behind the tile. Haven’t removed any tile yet but wanted to just regrout a row of tile.
Can I just regrout it carefully?


Is there a question?

Tiles are not put on drywall

@Traveler huh??

When you push it, if it feels spongy then you have something to worry about.  But if it feels stiff, then I would just regrout it.

@Traveler, maybe they shouldn't be (especially in a wet environment) but they often are.
